# NgRx StoreModule.forRoot - specify metareducers when there is no root level reducer

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

My project does not have a root reducer, it only has feature states.

I saw in this [issue](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/785) that we can use: `StoreModule.forRoot({})`. This is great, but I also need to specify metareducers. I've tried: `StoreModule.forRoot({}, { metaReducers })` but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just tested locally and it works. I think you need to share the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

The way described in the question is correct one, you need to import store in a current module or in any its parent.

```js
StoreModule.forRoot({}, {
  metaReducers,
});
```

If you get an error - it belongs to something else, but not to the `StoreModule.forRoot`.